# Cropped images set in two columns

Tags: html, css, image

I have images cropped to square shape set in two columns, but you can see that half of the second image is in the first column and second half is in the second column. It happens with odd number of images. How can I fix this?

And second thing is that sometimes my images fit 90px box but sometimes there are significantly bigger and I would like to scale them before cropping to fit the box. Is there a good way to do that?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1qjf2thq/

```
<ul>
  <li><div class="image"><a href="#" target="_blank"></a></div><div class="content">pony</div></li>
  <li><div class="image"><a href="#" target="_blank"></a></div><div class="content">pony</div></li>
  <li><div class="image"><a href="#" target="_blank"></a></div><div class="content">pony</div></li>
</ul>

ul {
    columns: 2;
    -webkit-columns: 2;
    -moz-columns: 2;
}

.image {
  background: url(http://wswieciekucykow.blog.pl/files/2014/06/pony4.png) 50% 50% no-repeat; 
  width: 90px; 
  height: 90px;
}

.image a {
  display: block; 
  width: 90px; 
  height: 90px
}

li .content {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

li .image, li .content { 
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/1qjf2thq/1/)?

I used `background-size : 100% 100%;` to make the image fit to the container.

I removed the columns on the `ul` and used `display: inline-block` on `li`.

Comment: Not exactly, because it's not going to work for rectangle images. These ones should be scaled and cropped to square instead of compressed to fit the box.

Comment: Not really because I want to scale it a little bit before cropping that I don't see only small part of a picture. But it probably requires javascript rather than css. Thanks for repairing spreading image into two columns.

Comment: You can play with CSS and background-size to get the desired output : https://jsfiddle.net/1qjf2thq/3/

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I wanted.